# can i can use two group by in sql query

Tags: sql

I have these two tables:

Covids

```
    | CovidId | StaffId | CovidStartDate | CovidFinishDate | 
      -------   -------   --------------   ---------------
        1           1       21.01.2021         15.01.2021
        2           1       26.04.2021         16.04.2021
        3           2       21.02.2021         14.01.2021
        4           3       22.03.2021         17.03.2021
        5           3       15.04.2021         30.04.2021
```

WorkingHours

```
    | WorkId | StaffId | WorkHours| 
     -------   -------   ---------
        1          1          8
        2          2          9
        3          3          8
```

I want to show how many times they had covid by working hour
expected result

```
    | WorkHour | CovidCount| 
     -------      -------   
        8           4          
        9           1
```

I wrote these SQL statements, but I was unable to bring them together:

```
SELECT StaffId, COUNT(*) AS covidCount 
FROM Covids 
GROUP BY StaffId

SELECT WorkHours 
FROM WorkingHours 
GROUP BY WorkHours
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Please add the expected result to the question.

Comment: i added @TheImpaler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course two separate queries won't "unite". You need to join the tables and then do the aggregation.

```
SELECT w.workhours AS workhour,
       count(*) AS covidcount
       FROM workinghours AS w
            LEFT JOIN covids AS c
                      ON c.staffid = w.staffid
       GROUP BY w.workhours;
```

Comment: instead of left join, inner join ?

Comment: @azoss: That would leave out working hours with no ... whatever the other thing is, i.e. a count of `0`.

Comment: can you look this my new problem ? please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479655/convert-this-sql-query-to-an-equivalent-linq-query